# Open CllLog on Android and pick a number

Tags: android, android-intent, calllog

I've read many posts of people trying to explain ho to open the call-log on Android and allow the user to pick an item but non of them work.
Does someone have a good working sample?

Answer (score 1):

The Following Code Snippet Works Perfectly fine with me

```
Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
context.startActivity(showCallLog);
```

Comment: The action i need is PICK and not view, i want the user to choose a call log entry.

Comment: Using this u will get native call log screen and you can perform action like click particular contact and other things etc

Comment: The native call log will be displayed, that's ok, but i need to know which entry the user clicked on. How do you get that info?

Answer (score 0):

I got this going using my own version.  i used a dialog and handed it the cursor to the call log. Here is the function:

```
public void getCallLog() {

    String[] callLogFields = { android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME /* im not using the name but you can*/};
    String viaOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    String WHERE = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " >0"; /*filter out private/unknown numbers */

    final Cursor callLog_cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, callLogFields,
            WHERE, null, viaOrder);

    AlertDialog.Builder myversionOfCallLog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getActivity());

    android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
            callLog_cursor.moveToPosition(item);

            Log.v("number", callLog_cursor.getString(callLog_cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)));

            callLog_cursor.close();

        }
    };
    myversionOfCallLog.setCursor(callLog_cursor, listener,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    myversionOfCallLog.setTitle("Choose from Call Log");
    myversionOfCallLog.create().show();
}
```